# Jquery Conflict Issue Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, jquery

i have added custom slider with for products. I added Jquery files. When I add jQuery files in XML then slider working but Add to Cart Button not working. When I remove jQuery files then, Slider obviously not working but Add to Cart button working Properly. Please Guide me I'm sharing link of my site:

t1.mygarden.pk

Comment: please check jquery lib file are included several time on pag

Comment: Thanks For reply :-), Have you check included files?

Comment: http://t1.mygarden.pk/skin/frontend/rwd/mygarden/js/jquery.js                                                        2) http://t1.mygarden.pk/skin/frontend/rwd/mygarden/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: remove one jquery

Comment: THank you for your quick Response, If i remove any file then slider not working. Check now i have removed jquery-1.10.2.min.js file, but now slider is not working and Add to Cart button working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using $ to show your slideshow...do the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
             jQuery('#target').slideshow();
        });
```

Comment: you are welcome...happy coding!!!