# jQuery conflicts in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, prototype-js, conflict

Generally we get jQuery and prototype.js conflicts in Magento 1.9
Mainly due to jQuery conflicts.
Do you have any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Conflict Issue Magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/jquery-conflict-issue-magento-1-9)

AND 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113255/remove-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype-js-in-magento-1-9-1

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution for it, you follow below instructions:

1) Add jQuery library in your layout xml e.g. page.xml

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js</script></action>
```

2) Add your custom js (in which you are using jQuery) just after jQuery like:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/theme.js</name></action>
```

3) After that include noconflict.js like:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
```

You should use, default jquery library from js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js.

So, finally it will look like:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/theme.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
```

if you are including jQuery through .phtml file instead of xml, then just following above order for files to be included.

Above implementation resolved my issue. I hope it will help you to resolve jQuery conflicts, in this way you could use jQuery and prototype-js as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js or some of its latest version and include after jquery-1.12.0.min.js.Check following link to download library.

```
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate
```